# Linkedin API :: search for keyword in "Licenses & certifications"

Tags: api, rest, postman, linkedin-api, google-search

I'm currently studying to obtain a Microsoft MCSA certification.

I would like to scrape LinkedIn in order to understand how many people in the World own a MCSA certification.

I'm currently searching into the LinkedIn Documentation but there are no [example](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/concepts/methods) that could help me search for a keyword in the "Licenses & certifications". The API documentation is vague.

Can you suggest me a Postman API call or a Python piece of code that could help me out?

**EDIT:**

I found out I  can search that easily through Google by using some search operators:

```
site:linkedin.com/in/ AND "MCSA: SQL Server 2012/2014"
```

So it turns out there are around 9.240 people on linkedIn who mention that certification:

[image]

I can then refine the search and use:

```
site:linkedin.com/in/ AND "MCSA: SQL Server 2012/2014" AND "France"
```

And it turns out there are 301 certifications in France:

[image]

I would like to target the class in the LinkedIn page that reference the country, following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/code-search/reference) I indeed can, I just have to target `class:"t-16 t-black t-normal inline-block"`:

[image]

But if I try to search for:

```
site:linkedin.com/in/ AND "MCSA: SQL Server 2012/2014" AND (class:"t-16 t-black t-normal inline-block" AND "France")
```

[image]

No joy.

So do you have any idea how to ultimately scrape LinkedIn through `Postman`, `Python` or `Google Search`?

Comment: You can use selenium / Beautifulsoup to search query (without class one) and login in Linkedin then after opening specific page you extract the desired keyword.

Comment: Also available Python interface https://pypi.org/project/python-linkedin-v2/

Comment: Thank you @Posi2, trying it out now

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I have to put this as an answer. If you go to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/consumer/context#retrieve-other-members-profile) you'll see the documentation for the linked in profile api. You however need specific permissions to use this, so you will have to request approval from linked in. If you then get access to this you can get the [certification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/certification?context=linkedin/consumer/context) profile field, and that should be applicable for what you are looking for. There is also a [location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/location?context=linkedin/consumer/context) field as well. For the query you would also need a findermethod as talked about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/methods?context=linkedin/consumer/context) since you want to search by those two profile fields instead of the profileid.

Comment: Add resources(photos & code) in the answer bcoz later links break and make answer incomplete.

Comment: Thank you, LinkedIn is reviewing my subscription for the API_KEY